# Small signal resistor of emitter in CE voltage amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image: ce]
in such a small signal model of CE circuit. Why "re" ( the small signal resistor of the emitter = VT/IE ) is not represented? However, I've noticed that it is shown in CE amplifier with emitter degeneration  and also in CB, but not in CE without emitter degeneration nor CC amplifier circuits!

Answer (score -1):

> Why "re" ( the small signal resistor of the emitter = VT/IE ) is not represented?

because it is internal to the device -> that's why it is in that shaded box.

Comment: In the shaded box I see r(pi) and ro. Not re,?

Comment: @utdlegend Because this time \$re\$ is hiding inside \$r_{\pi}\$. As we all know \$r_{\pi} = \frac{v_{be}}{i_b} = \frac{\beta}{gm} = (\beta+1)*re \$ and \$gm = V_T/I_C = \frac{\beta}{(\beta+1)*re}\$